# Counting, finding certain letter and percentage

Tags: python, string, percentage, alpha

I am working on this question and cannot find the right answer but I have managed to dig a bigger hole & confuse myself. So if anyone can provide clarity:

DIRECTIONS:

Write a function analyze_text that receives a string as input. Your function should count the number of alphabetic characters (a through z, or A through Z) in the text and also keep track of how many are the letter 'e' (upper or lowercase).

Your function should return an analysis of the text in the form of a string phrased exactly like this:

“The text contains 240 alphabetic characters, of which 105 (43.75%) are ‘e’.”

You will need to make use of the isalpha function.

MY CODE so far:
    def analyze_text(text):
        count = 0
        letter_count = 0

```
for char in text:
    if char.isalpha():
        count += 1
for e in text:
    if e == "e" or e =="E":
        letter_count += 1
    p = float(letter_count)/float(count) * 100

analyze.text = "The text contains {0} alphabetic characters, of 
which {1} ({2}) are 'e'."
print(analyze_text.format(count += 1, letter_count += 1, p))

TESTS that are given:
# Note that depending on whether you use str.format or 
string concatenation

# your code will pass different tests. Code passes either
# tests 1-3 OR tests 4-6.

from test import testEqual

# Tests 1-3: solutions using string concatenation should pass these
text1 = "Eeeee"
answer1 = "The text contains 5 alphabetic characters, 
of which 5 (100.0%) are 'e'."
testEqual(analyze_text(text1), answer1)

text2 = "Blueberries are tasteee!"
answer2 = "The text contains 21 alphabetic characters, of 
which 7 (33.3333333333%) are 'e'."
testEqual(analyze_text(text2), answer2)

text3 = "Wright's book, Gadsby, contains a total of 0 of 
that most common symbol ;)"
answer3 = "The text contains 55 alphabetic characters, 
of which 0 (0.0%) are 'e'."
testEqual(analyze_text(text3), answer3)

# Tests 4-6: solutions using str.format should pass these
text4 = "Eeeee"
answer4 = "The text contains 5 alphabetic characters, 
of which 5 (100%) are 'e'."
testEqual(analyze_text(text4), answer4)

text5 = "Blueberries are tasteee!"
answer5 = "The text contains 21 alphabetic characters, 
of which 7 (33.33333333333333%) are 'e'."
testEqual(analyze_text(text5), answer5)

text6 = "Wright's book, Gadsby, contains a total of 
0 of that most common symbol ;)"
answer6 = "The text contains 55 alphabetic characters, 
of which 0 (0%)     are 'e'."
testEqual(analyze_text(text6), answer6)
```

Comment: you need to show what errors you're getting otherwise you wont get any assistance but you will get plenty of down votes

Comment: Very close, but instead of printing the answer string you need to return it. Also, you could be a bit more efficient by incrementing count and letter_count inside the same loop.

Answer (score 0):

There are only a couple things wrong outlined below in the comments:

```
def analyze_text(text):
    count = 0
    letter_count = 0
    for char in text:
        if char.isalpha():
            count += 1
    for e in text:
        if e == "e" or e == "E":
            letter_count += 1
    p = float(letter_count) / float(count) * 100

    # here, you put a period instead of an underscore in analyze_text
    # you also forgot to put the percent sign "%"
    analyze_text = "The text contains {0} alphabetic characters, of which {1} ({2}%) are 'e'."

    # you don't need to add 1 to count and letter_count using += 1
    # they are already the correct values
    # also, you should return the string here, not print it
    return analyze_text.format(count, letter_count, p)
```

That code should get you the desired results that you showed in the question

Answer (score 0):

```
def analyze_text(text, letter='e'):
    n = len([x for x in text if x.isalpha()])
    freq = text.lower().count(letter)
    percent = float(freq) / n * 100
    return "The text contains {} alphabetic characters, of which {} ({}%) are '{}'.".format(n, freq, percent, letter)
```

Answer (score 0):

Taking a quick glance at your work, it appears as if you're using your replacement fields incorrectly. Your code:

```
print(analyze_text.format(count += 1, letter_count += 1, p))
```

Correct version:

```
print(output.format(count, letter_count, p))
```

Here is what your function should look like:

```
def analyze_text(text):
    count = 0
    letter_count = 0
    for char in text:
        if char.isalpha():
            count += 1
    for e in text:
        if e == "e" or e == "E":
            letter_count += 1
        p = float(letter_count)/float(count) * 100
    output = "The text contains {0} alphabetic characters, of which {1} ({2}%) are 'e'."
    print(output.format(count, letter_count, p))
```

You should treat your formatter as a list. Your replacement fields correspond to the order in the list. Hope that clarifies things up.

P.S. - You forgot the % sign in the output message.